# Should time range checks be inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: python

The general convention for a generic range `(x,y)` is that x is inclusive and y is exclusive.

For Python `datetime.time` type, `datetime.time.max` is `time(23, 59, 59, 999999)`, so it doesn't seem to allow to use the conventional range check on the upper end. For example, if I want to check a time range between 10 am and midnight, I might want a range like this: `(time(10), time(24))`. But `time(24)` is not valid, even as a sentinel value.

On the other hand, we can't make x exclusive and y inclusive, because then we lose `time(0)` as a value.

Should range checks on time be inclusive? Something about it doesn't seem right to me, but I can't articulate it.

Comment: If you use `datetime` instead of `time` you can use midnight of the following day as your upper bound.  But if you don't actually care about the date you would need a dummy value there (1970-1-1 and 1970-1-2, maybe?) which is a bit of a hack.

Comment: I notice that the error message for `datetime.time(24)` is `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`. Since 0 and 23 are both permissible values, this may indicate the author's preference about incluvisity of end points in the context of times.

Comment: I suppose the issue does not really come up in practice, because you would not generally check a time in a finite range of time values. You would check it by using inequalities, so choosing `<` or `<=` as you want. For same reason we don't check floats in a range of floats.

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate all the thoughts expressed here. It seems that the practical approach to time ranges depends on the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0 for midnight

Instead of:

```py
(time(10), time(24))
```

Use:

```py
# From midnight (0:00) to 10am (10:00)
(time(0), time(10))
```